# How to print count of distinct student id's in this partial view based on model

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

How can I get count of distinct student id's  based on partial view model. I have a model which has result but i want to have a label saying StudentIdCount and print number of distinct student Id's there

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.StudentInfo>
@(Html


            .Grid(Model)
            .Build(columns =>
            {

                columns.Add(model => model.StudentId).Titled("StudentId");
                columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
            })
            .Empty("No records found.")
            .Sortable()
            .Pageable(pager =>
            {
                pager.RowsPerPage = 15;
            })
)
```

I tried this below but does not work

```
 @model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.StudentInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Count = Model.Select(x => x.StudentId).Distinct().Count();

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Count: ViewBag.Count</label>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@model IEnumerable<CSA.Models.ReportsInfo>
    @(Html


                .Grid(Model)
                .Build(columns =>
                {

                    columns.Add(model => model.StudentId).Titled("StudentId");
                    columns.Add(model => model.Name).Titled("Name");
                })
                .Empty("No records found.")
                .Sortable()
                .Pageable(pager =>
                {
                    pager.RowsPerPage = 15;
                })
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an option .WithGridItemsCount(string totalRecords) which allows you to display the total count. Hope to help, my friend:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApp.Models.StudentInfo>
    @{
        var inputStudentId = XXX; 
        var totalRecords = 0;
        if(inputStudentId != 0) //if the user want to search StudentId
        {
        totalRecords  = Model.Where(x => x.StudentId == inputStudentId).Select(x => x.StudentId).Distinct().Count();
}else
{
       totalRecords  = Model.Select(x => x.StudentId).Distinct().Count();
}


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Count: @totalRecords </label>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: But what I am looking for is I want to do something like this  `ViewBag.Count = Model.Count(x => x.StudentId);` but also add distinct

Comment: @sgl: You can use this query: Model.Select(x => x.StudentId).Distinct().Count(), my friend.

Comment: Please check if my code is correct...Updated Question

Comment: @sgl: I edited it follow your question. Hope to help, my friend!

Comment: If I use this way my search filter is not working. I mean if I search with some student id its not working

Comment: @sgl: I edited my solution. You should post full of your requirement. So everybody can help you better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177661/discussion-between-sgl-and-tomato32).